# Rational Topologcial Spaces - What is the Difference?

Tags: general-topology

Occasionally I heard people discuss topology spaces in the environment of rational spaces $\mathbb{Q}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example a sphere is defined as $$S^n=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}|x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=1\},$$
instead of 
$$S^n=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}|x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=1\}.$$

Other notions such as simplexes and unit intervals can be defined similarly. Thus one can further defined homotopy, CW-complex, etc.

---

My questions:

1. If spaces are defined in this way, are the results still the same as the traditional ones? Is there any significant difference at all?
2. What if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$ (quarternions), etc.?

Comment: The reals aren't inherent to topology as a subject so it's hard to see what you mean by replacing them. It just so happens that the spaces we find the easiest to handle are those built from gluing pieces of $n$-dimensional real space together, and so we study these spaces disproportionately to the others.

Comment: @DanielRust, I mean if you define spheres, intervals, etc. as subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ for sufficiently large $n$, then we can defined many other notions this way. Thus we can have, for example, a new definition of $\pi_m(S^n)$. Is this group still the same as the usual $\pi_m(S^n)$?

Comment: So for instance would your notion of a homotopy between maps $f,g\colon X\to Y$ be a map $H\colon X\times (\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])\to Y$ such that $H(-,0)=f$ and $H(-,1)=g$?

Comment: @DanielRust, I would think so. Do you think it is a good way to define homotopy?

Comment: In many case (I think we need $Y$ to be normal and path connected maybe?) this definition will coincide with the usual definition because it is often the case that a map $\mathbb{Q}\to Y$ is continuous iff it has an extension to a continuous map $\mathbb{R]\to Y$.

Answer (score 2):

The results will be very different for ${\bf Q}$. For one, it is not a Polish space: it is not completely metrisable. Many familiar properties of ${\bf R}$ rely on the complete metric (Baire theorem, Heine-Borel theorem, for instance) and fail when there is no such thing.

It is also totally disconnected: the only connected components are points. That also makes the supposed “rational homotopy” useless: a continuous map from ${\bf Q}$ can jump without any problems (at the missing irrational points). In general, continuity in rational spaces can be far from what you would expect from a well-behaved continuous maps.

With ${\bf C}$ or ${\bf H}$ you would have no such problems. They are simply isometric to ${\bf R}^2$ and ${\bf R}^4$, so they are topologically and metrically indistinguishable, so there is not much of a point in discussing these in purely topological terms.

Comment: What do you mean by "a continuous map from $\mathbb{Q}$ can jump"? In my understanding, if $f$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}^+$, there exists $\delta\in\mathbb{Q}^+$, ... (everyone knows the rest)

Comment: @zuriel for instance the image of $\mathbb{Q}$ under a continuous map can lie within two distinct connected components of a space for example $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\{0,1\}$ given by $f(x)=0$ if $x<\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @DanielRust, in your example we can choose $a<\sqrt{2}<a+\epsilon$ with $a,\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ but $f(a+\epsilon)-f(a)=1$ and thus $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: @zuriel: It is continuous. $\sqrt2\notin {\bf Q}$, so it doesn't make sense to check continuity at this point. For any $a<\sqrt 2$ there is an $\varepsilon$ such that $a+\varepsilon<\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @tomasz, I see! Thus homotopy groups are all trivial. Then what if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$? Should we define homotopy as a map $F$ from $X\times [0,1]\times[0,1]\to Y$ such that $F|_{X\times(0,0)}=f$ and $F|_{X\times(1,1)}=g$?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are homotopic in the usual sense, then they will be homotopic in the above sense by simply defining the map $F(x,t,s)=H(x,\frac{1}{2}(t+s))$. Similarly the converse holds by defining $H(x,t)=F(x,t,t)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The closed intervals need not be compact [eg., $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:\sqrt{2}\leq x\leq\sqrt{3}\}$]
2. It is not a complete metric space.
3. It is not path connected. And hence it is not contractible.

Comment: Why is $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ a closed interval?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I mean the usual concepts are considered as subspaces of $\mathbb{Q}^n$. For example, the closed interval $[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}]$ does not make sense. And I think $I$, when defined as $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$, is still path connected as the definition of path is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, is the order topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ the same as that inherited from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: $(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)\cap {\bf Q}$ is not a closed interval in order-theoretic sense. But it is a convex, closed set. More to the point, *no* set containing an interval (in particular, no nontrivial convex set) is compact.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I think so. Or one may consider $\mathbb{Q}^n$ as a metric space with the Euclidean metric and define topology accordingly.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: And yes, the order topologies coincide, because any real interval is the union of rational intervals contained within.